# Error 'Invalid hostname for this tenancy' on using graph api of sharepoint to subscribe event notification

Tags: c#, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

I am new to sharepoint and now I am trying to create a webhook for my sharepoint sites, such that on any crud operation i would get notification in my app

I have created a webapp to receive notification and console application to subscribe notification, I used Microsoft graph api by referring [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/webhooks?view=graph-rest-1.0) document to create subscription

Now the issue is when i give following in my [subscription request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example)

```
Resource = "sites/{siteName}/lists/{listId}"
```

It does hit in my notification web app from where i respond 200 ok, but then in my console web application it throws error saying "Invalid hostname for this tenancy"

I am not sure about my resource id, is there any suggestion for my SharePoint site resource

Comment: if you query `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{siteName}/lists/{listId}` do you get a response?

Comment: I don't know about the poster, but I get unauthorized. I've been using https://{tenant-name}.sharepoint.com/sites/{site-name}/_api to access the rest api. I'm trying to change to the graph api.

Comment: @N-ate these are the SharePoint REST APIs. It's a different set of APIs and if you requested a token for MS Graph but are sending your requests to SP REST APIs, it's by design. Let's try to focus on the original question however.
rahul, any thoughts on my original comment?

Comment: I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891220/unable-to-access-the-sharepoint-list-using-microsoft-graph-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access the Sharepoint List using Microsoft Graph API--](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43891220/unable-to-access-the-sharepoint-list-using-microsoft-graph-api)

Answer (score 2):

Generally you would get this error when your hostname is wrong. For ex: here is the valid way of getting a site

```
var site = await graphClient.Sites.GetByPath("/sites/{siteName}","{companyName}.sharepoint.com");
```

We should not add https:// in the hostname.